# but now it's not about me

Tags: idiomatic-language

> **Man:** *I don't want to talk about it. I doubt you'd find it particularly interesting to hear about, either.*
>
> **Psychologist:** *...Probably not. But **now** it's not about me. It's about you.*

Hi. In my language, which is Danish, **now** would be perfectly natural here, but would it also be natural in English? From the research I've done it doesn't seem to be.

Comment: I'd say _right now_. _Now_ on its own leaves me wondering what the Psychologist meant. I'd probably take it to refer to a previous conversation which was about the Psychologist, but that seems unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "But now it's not about me"is not **unnatural** but it is perhaps a little unusual. I think a more usual way of expressing this thought in US English would be something like one of:

> - But **here** it's not about me. It's about you.
> - But **in this conversation** it's not about me. It's about you.
> - But **when we talk** it's not about me. It's about you.

Comment: Which research have you done, and what did it show?

Ignoring the research you didn't Post, I'd go with David's 'not unnatural, but perhaps a little unusual', with the emphasis very clearly on 'not unnatural…'

Since you mention Danish, I happen to know at least a score of Danes who would not think once about Questioning that passage…

Most native speakers would never think of Questioning that passage…

Even if you doubt all of that, why are you questioning that passage?

What other phrasing would you suggest that might have the same meaning?